# How to integrate aadhar api/SDKs for get user basics detail in react native mobile app?

Tags: react-native

I want to integrate aadhar api or aadhar sdk for get use basics details in react native mobile app if any help and proper example it's appreciate and thanks:-Vinod Takhar

I read only document that provided on UDID official side but not get any specific solutions for react native mobile application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.